# Pros/cons of the different schemes to have complete fault-tolerant gatesets

Tags: error-correction, resource-request, fault-tolerance, magic-states

I am interested to have references and comment about pro/cons of the various methods that are used to implement complete gateset in a fault tolerant manner.

Usually the Clifford operations have a standard way to be implemented fault-tolerantly, at least in concatenated code (which I know best), by implementing them transversally. But it has been shown that it is not possible to have a complete gateset only based on transversal gates implementation. For this reason, for the non-clifford operations, other techniques are usually required. There is for what I know:

- Magic state distillation ([ref](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403025))
- Gate teleportation ([ref](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9908010.pdf))

I have heard about other techniques like

- Code switching techniques (two codes $A$ and $B$ are able to implement different transversal gate such that the union of those gates form a complete gateset. You then decode the state from $A$ to encode it to $B$ when you need to perform a transversal gate allowed by $B$)
- Some codes admit a nice construction for a complete fault-tolerant gateset.

In the answer, **I would be interested to know why magic state distillation is so popular those days**, given the number of publications in this topic (because there are many other techniques). There is probably some clear advantage over other techniques that I don't see.

Comment: A nice starting point may be the list in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastin–Knill_theorem) wikipedia article.

Answer (score 2):

Magic state distillation is the most popular because it is (as of yet) the most efficient. Also, magic state distillation *fuels* gate teleportation, so I wouldn't say it's used instead of gate teleportation. The biggest advantage state distillation has is that it can use error detecting codes instead of error correcting codes, and this has a tendency to double the code distance at no additional cost.

[Michael Beverland et al looked at the cost of code switching](https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/abstract/10.1103/PRXQuantum.2.020341) and found "[no] substantial savings over state distillation" despite using more complex connectivity (a 3d code instead of a 2d code for the code switching).

Caution: you should ignore the orange curves because there's no corresponding "optimistic state distillation" to compare it to.

[image]

(The 2d surface code has transversal Clifford gates when you can stack interacting layers, so you would expect state distillation cost to drop if you had access to a 3d topology.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure to understand why you say that it fuels gate teleportation ? Maybe for some schemes but from what I known fault tolerant gate teleportation was known before magic state distillation so it is not "in principle" necessary to use magic states *distillation* for that ? Also, it appears that your paper is very recent so I am wondering if there is a "good enough" consensus on the fact state distillation is better of if it is actually still an open question against other schemes.

Comment: @StarBuck oh it is definitely still an open question! But the best non-Clifford technique for the past decade or so has consistently been magic state distillation, so there's an expectation that is hard to beat. But consider S gates. In the surface code the state of the art for that has switched from distillation to twists.